# Is there a way to make JTable set class by row instead of column

Tags: java, string, image, swing, jtable

Is there a way to make `JTable` set class by row instead of the column? I want my table to look like this:

```
image image image image
text  text  text  text
image image image image
text  text  text  text
```

The first-row class is `Image` while the second-row class is `String` class.

Comment: This is not a good candidate for a table structure. If the text relates to the image (e.g. 'image with caption below') I'd instead use a single `JLabel` for each, in a `GridLayout`. The label can be configured to show the text below the icon.

Comment: Or a JList with a custom renderer which can be configured to display items in a row/column format. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Initializing a List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#init)

Comment: @camickr Yeah .. I like your `JList` suggestion better than `GridLayout`.. With a list, the number of images per row can be fluidly adjusted (automatically) when the user resizes the window width.